# how do I re attach git to local directory

Tags: git, github

I have a laravel project created locally which I later created a repository for in GitHub.

Recently due to some issue I deleted my `.git/` folder from local disk which resulted in losing connection with the remote repository situated in GitHub.

I want to re attach my local files to that repository, but I do not want any files to change.
Is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

One possible resolution:

- clone your GitHub repository in a new local folder
- move the `.git/` subfolder folder back to your current project folder (the one where you deleted your `.git/` folder in the first place)
- do a `git status` to check everything seems as expected.

A `git remote -v` should show you the connection (remote `origin`) back in pace.